# Run mysql scheduler in windows start up

Tags: mysql, windows, stored-procedures

I am using **mysql version 5.5.12-log**. In my system i am using a scheduler. But **if the server restarted then the scheduler don't work**. That time i have to use the following command to enable the scheduler again.It's really difficult to remember to run the query again & again when system restarted.How can i fix it.

My commands:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write "**event_scheduler=ON**"  line into "**my.ini**" file,under the clause [mysqld] located in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5".My windows version is "Windows7",MySql version is: 5.5.12. Now restart the server and check the variable "`SELECT @@event_scheduler`" is "**ON**". for detail please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942354/why-this-mysql-event-cant-get-run) and [link2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)