# SQL Event doesn't run

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

```
 ALTER EVENT reset_monthly
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MONTH
    STARTS '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
COMMENT 'Descriptive comment' 
DO
    TRUNCATE sequence_code_os;
```

This event fails to delete all rows of sequence_code_os monthly. Why ?

Comment: Does it work if you run the `TRUNCATE` command by hand?

Comment: Is your event scheduler running? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942354/why-this-mysql-event-cant-get-run/942411#942411

Comment: TRUNCATE might fail if you have any foreign keys in your table (even if there are no actual dependencies at the moment). Try disabling them during the command if the other alternatives don't work

Comment: Or replace it with `DELETE FROM sequence_code_os;`

Comment: It worked. Event scheduler was not running