# Scheduled MySQL event not firing

Tags: mysql, events

I created this event. It shoud be fired automatically once per day.

```
CREATE EVENT  Get_Price_Daily  
ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 1 DAY     
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE          
DO       

insert into graph(ean, avg_price) select ean, round(avg(price),2) avg_price from pt_products group by ean;
```

But it does not fire automatically.

If I check for the scheduled events:

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```

It shows this:
[image]

The vesion I use is

```
5.7.25-28-log
```

Why it is not firing every day?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the event scheduler is enabled?

Comment: ... check `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` for a record, where `User = 'event_scheduler'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why this mysql event can't get run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942354/why-this-mysql-event-cant-get-run)