# Creater MYSQL event update days remaining

Tags: mysql, xampp

I want to update my days remaining every day with current date minus the date of expiration.

```
CREATE EVENT check_expire
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2023-10-25'
DO
UPDATE documents_recieved
SET days_remaining = (DATEDIFF(expiration_date, CURRENT_DATE));
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: my start date was 2023-10-18 yesterday and upon checking today nothing happen on column of days_reamining.

Comment: Your code has the 25th , but check if the event handler is activated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/942411/20860 for my answer on checking the event scheduler and enabling it if needed.