Troubleshooting MySQL Event for Daily Table Reset
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT reset_daily_learning_info
on schedule every 1 day
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
BEGIN
  UPDATE daily_learning_info
  SET studied = 0, amount = 0;
END;
DELIMITER ;

This is my mysql event, it should reset a table named "daily_learning_info" in everyday.
But it doesn't do that. I don't know the problem. How can I resolve this? please help me!

Check UPDATE status (matched and effected rows). Try to add fake WHERE (for example, WHERE id > 0).

Is your event scheduler running? See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/942411/20860

Both comments were so helpful, thanks guys!!
